# can't detect default python version

Tags: python, default

```
~$ python
bash: python: command not found
```

**while running python2 and python 3 its showing different versions.**

```
~$ python2
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

~$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

i think somehow default python link is broken. i can't seem to access ubuntu software center also.

Please suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: Yes, you have screwed up your system python, also python2 and python3 should show different versions. Did you remove the symlink to python2?

Comment: `sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-creating the simlink as suggested, I would start working with virtualenv. You can create virtual environment pointing at different python versions by doing:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 venv_name  (for Python 2.7)
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv_name  (for Python 3)
```

Once you go into the venv and do the source venv_name/bin/activate, your python symbolic link will be pointed at the version you've chosen when creating it.

Also, you might find a pyvenv link which will be associated to Python 3 as this version of Python comes with virtualenv (and pip) out of the box. You might need to install virtualenv with pip (or easy install), and to figure it out which Pythonversion is your pip associated to, you can do `pip --version`